# Embed HTML Image into Folium Popup

Tags: python, iframe, folium

How can I embed an HTML image into a Folium Popup? I am able to place a png image into my Folium Popup with no issue, however, when I try to use the same logic with an HTML image (more specifically a plotly figure) my popup is just a blank white box. My file path is confirmed to be correct. I'm out of ideas as to how to fix this :(

Below is a snipit of the the code I used to embed the png into my popup.

```py
html1 ='<iframe src="data:image/png;base64,{}"\>'.format
encoded = base64.b64encode(open('example.png', 'rb').read()).decode()
iframe = IFrame(html1(encoded), width=200+20, height=200+20)
 
folium.Marker(
location = (df_beet_20.Lat[i], df_beet_20.Long[i]),
popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=1000),
icon = folium.Icon(
icon = i_dict['Beetus'], color = c_dict['Beetus'])).add_to(beetus_20)
```

Here is a snipit of the result I am getting when I try to embed the plotly hmtl figure:
[Blank white box:(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjjXi.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Below is a sample of some of the things I have tried to get this to work, but to no avail.

```py
html1 = '<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,{}"></iframe>'.format
encoded = base64.b64encode(open('Erie_fig.html', 'rb').read()).decode()

marker = folium.Marker(
    location=(df_beet_20.Lat[i], df_beet_20.Long[i]),
    icon=folium.Icon(icon=i_dict['Beetus'], color=c_dict['Beetus'])).add_to(beetus_20)

from folium import IFrame
iframe = IFrame(html1(encoded), width=200+20, height=200+20)
folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=1000).add_to(marker)
```

This returns to me the blank white box.

```py
with open('Erie_fig.html', 'r') as f:
html = f.read()
encoded = base64.b64encode(html.encode()).decode()
iframe = IFrame(html, width=600, height=400)
marker = folium.Marker(
    location=(df_beet_20.Lat[i], df_beet_20.Long[i]),
    popup=folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=1000),
    icon=folium.Icon(icon=i_dict['Beetus'], color=c_dict['Beetus']))
marker.add_to(beetus_20)
```

This returns to me a giant figure with no map :(